# url.indexOf is Not function почему то на нижнию строку жалуется?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
    var selector, type, response,
        self = this,
        off = url.indexOf( " " );
```

Кто знает как переписать верно ? не знаю куда `.trigger .on` поставить!

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:9793 Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:9793)
    at 50341:739
```

Comment: `url` точно строка?

Comment: @gil9red да точно эта строка

Comment: @Badzilla92: нет, это не строка. + Вы используете устаревшее API jQuery. + Кто сегодня вообще использует jQuery?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, [оффтоп] а что сегодня используют вместо jQuery? :)

Comment: @gil9red: Вы не поверите! JavaScript хД

Comment: @gil9red:  https://www.commitstrip.com/en/2013/10/23/et-si-on-venait-de-trouver-le-meilleur-framework-js-ever/

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, у меня опыт небольшой в js, но использование jQuery для отправки ajax было очень удобным. А из коробки для этой цели нужно было поддерживать дикую спагетти, пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567149/5909792

Comment: @gil9red: скоро подъедет Fluent API. Да и не ставить же из-за одного только $.ajax jQuery, правда?

Comment: @gil9red: я вот себе такую штуку сваял и сижу довольный:  https://github.com/Kir-Antipov/SimpleAjax